# How to add a new key in result of codeigniter model return result()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a function in my model that get all company details I am fetch this 
I have to add a new key city_name in my return result() how can I add ?? I am very confused but I am not get any useable example.

```
function xxxx($search=array(),$page,$limit){
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("xxx");
    $this->db->join("xx","xx.xx=xxx.xx");

    $this->db->limit($limit,$page);
    $company_data = $this->db->get();
    if($company_data->num_rows()){
        return $company_data->result();
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Save your result in a variable let's say `$result`. Then add a new property using `$result->city_name = 'somevalue'` OR `$result['city_name'] = 'somevalue'`

Comment: @RehbanKhatri this is $result->city_name = 'somevalue' is not working and i have to use result() only thank you i know this is  $result['city_name'] = 'somevalue' working

Comment: num-rows has to have a value ($query->num_rows() > 0) ($query->num_rows() = 1) etc

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line:

```
return $company_data->result();    // It return Stc Class Object
```

to

```
return $company_data->result_array();   // Now it returns an array
```

Now you can use `array_push()` function, it inserts one or more elements to the end of an array.
Or simply use:

```
$company_data['index'] = value;
```

Comment: i have to user result()

Answer (score 0):

Keep your model same `return $company_data->result()`.

In your controller, you need to iterate it for the number of results you get and add new key to your objects.(`result()` method returns `Standard Class Object`).

```
function yourControllerMethod()
{
  $company_data = $this->your_model->xxx(search_array, $page, $limit);
  if(!empty($company_data)
  {
    foreach($company_data as $cd)
    {
       $cd->city_name = "pune"; // or anything you want
    }
  }
  var_dump($company_data);
}
```

Try this to add new key to your results.

Edit:

You asked that you don't have `city_name` key in your object.
Yes, you don't have. The above code adds a key in your object.
Just like array.

```
$temp = array();
$temp["id"] = 1;
```

In this code, initially the array is empty, the next statement add the `id` as key in the array.

Comment: There is no city name key in my result so I have to add it

Comment: Exactly, this code add that key ```city_name``` in your object.